# How to Disable Google Cloud Messaging From App server?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

How to disable the Google cloud Messaging (GCM) using the API call from my server, without going to the https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/googlecloudmessaging/overview

Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]

Is there any API available to do that?

Comment: Hey @Mohamed, unfortunately there is no API or document regarding to what you wanted to happen. Currently you can only disable GCM or other APIs of Google thru Google Developer Console.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot Thanks For the comment